# How would i create a vanity url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

How can i create a vanity url in codeigniter. Im having real trouble doing this in the framework. And there doesnt seem to be any good answers out there.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, I'm using this in one of my projects...

Here is a thread on the CodeIgniter forums showing how to do it...

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/113962/

Answer (score 1):

According to [Personalized User Vanity URL's in CodeIgniter](http://philpalmieri.com/2010/04/personalized-user-vanity-urls-in-codeigniter/), you can accomplish this by modifying your routes file:

```
$handle = opendir(APPPATH."/modules");
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  if(is_dir(APPPATH."/modules/".$file)){
    $route[$file] = $file;
    $route[$file."/(.*)"] = $file."/$1";
  }
}

/*Your custom routes here*/

/*Wrap up, anything that isnt accounted for pushes to the alias check*/
$route['([a-z\-_\/]+)'] = "aliases/check/$1";
```