# How to use domain.com/username in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri, codeigniter-url

As like facebook(facebook.com/userurl) I like to use `domain.com/username` in codeigniter. Here username is unique one. I want to create every register user have his/her own url(path). Can anyone help regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not URL. Understand the Concept. You having some Basic problem. Use that id as Parameter(GET method).

See this Image:
[image]

Get something? For [more...](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Getting-Parameters-From-GET-P151.html)

As your point use

```
$this->uri->segment(2);
```

[Link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

As your question,

```
localhost/codeigniter/ripon
```

this is your URL. So, in your default Controller,
**way 1:**

```
public function index($user)
{
    echo "User is ".$user;
}
```

**way 2:**

```
public function index()
{
    $user = $this->uri->segment(2);
    echo "User is ".$user;
}
```

Comment: Here "hello" is controller name and "you" is a function name. I didn't want to give it in url, I only want to give the username as parameter

Comment: Vanity URL is just tech word. Dont worry about that. Are you got or not? If no means, tell me where you stoped? And give some code.

Comment: Tell me how can I echo the user name when I put http://localhost/codeigniter/ripon. here ripon is user name. consider fresh download copy of CodeIgniter_2.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in routes.php file in configs before any custom routes

```
 $handle = opendir(APPPATH."/controllers");
 while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
 if(is_dir(APPPATH."/controllers/".$file)){
   $route[$file] = $file;
   $route[$file."/(.*)"] = $file."/$1";
 }
}

/*Your custom routes here*/

/*Wrap up, anything that isnt accounted for pushes to the alias check*/

$route['([a-z\-_\/]+)'] = "aliases/check/$1";
```

Please Refer these question - [How would i create a vanity url in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761259/how-would-i-create-a-vanity-url-in-codeigniter/2761316#2761316)

In brief, we check whether the controller and function name exist in the URL..IF it does then we route it to that function..Else we will send to aliases controller & check function to see if the user exist with that username.

Answer (score 0):

I get the desire solution form http://www.aamra24.com/how-to-use-domain-then-username-in-codeigniter/

You need to add following code to application/config/routes.php

```
$route['(.*)'] = "welcome/index/$1";
```